# How can I Host the WorkflowDesigner of WorkflowFoundation 4 in a Winforms application?

Tags: wpf, workflow-foundation-4

I don't have much explanation that the tittle himself, lol.

But, what I really want to do is load de WorkflowDesigner on an Winform ElementHost Control.

I try doing this: [Host WorkflowDesigner in a WPF Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489451.aspx), but it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new DesignerMetadata().Register(); //Missing Line

    des = new WorkflowDesigner();
    des.Load(mFileName);
    elementHost1.Child = des.View;
}
```

Only was needed to add the missing line "*new DesignerMetadata().Register();*"

Note: elementHost1 is a WinForm ElementHost Control, direct from the toolbox! ;)