# how to create workflow by user?

Tags: winforms, .net-4.0, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I Host the WorkflowDesigner of WorkflowFoundation 4 in a Winforms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045971/how-can-i-host-the-workflowdesigner-of-workflowfoundation-4-in-a-winforms-applic)

I am working on windows application and i face a problem, please help me.

In business rules, there are contracts between several organizations. 
Each contract has a lot of rules which make the support and design of system hard. 
Based on each contract, there is a different system workflow for calculation of contract.

I decide to use WF4.0  that user design a workflow for each contract, I think this is the best way.

Now my question is :
Can i have WF4.0 on windows form?

In fact, can i design a form which user makes a workflow with some drags or select?

Comment: See [How can I Host the WorkflowDesigner of WorkflowFoundation 4 in a Winforms application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045971/how-can-i-host-the-workflowdesigner-of-workflowfoundation-4-in-a-winforms-applic)

Comment: I wrote a blog post about this a while ago. See [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2009/12/23/rehosting-the-workflow-designer-in-wf4.aspx) for more details.